# Listen to key event dispatched on a drawer navigation fragment

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, keyevent

Im using the drawer navigation fragment and I want the fragment in it to listen to key events if the navigation drawer is open, whats the best way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can launch a broadcast from your drawer:

```
public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
   Intent i=new Intent();
   i.setAction("drawerout");
   getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(i);
   }
```

and receive it on your fragment:

```
onCreateView(){
   drawerReceiver=new DrawerReceiver();     
   registerReceiver(drawerReceiver, new IntentFilter("drawerout"));
   }

DrawerReceiver  drawerReceiver;
public class DrawerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   @Override 
   public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {   
       //do something here    
     }
   }
```